# Can Ubuntu support an n-monitors configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

I'd like to have 3 or even 4 monitors hooked up to my machine, so that I can have different applications open at the same time but not have everything cluttered all in one screen.

I know Ubuntu allows you to have 4 different "desktops" at any one point in time, but you still have to scroll from one to the other when you want to change to a different desktop. I want the ability to see all 4 at once.

How could such a configuration be made? Assume I'm using an ordinary HP laptop with one external monitor port. I assume I would need to hook into some kind of dock or special device that allows my video card to send data to 4 different monitors.

**What kind of device would this be??**

And, even if such a device exists, does Ubuntu even come with the OS features to support this kind of "n-monitor" setup? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hardware definitely exists to expand onto 3 monitors (Matrox TripleHead2Go) and it uses Linux, but I have not found anything to do 4 monitors in Linux.

Comment: Agree with @Tog...at least on a laptop.  An eGPU solution could probably do it, in theory, but you'd be on your own with getting the drivers to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With laptop with only on external monitor port you can **only** use splitter that will show same picuture on 4 monitors.

Comment: @Tog & Shinrai -  this seems to contradict your statements - anybody care to weigh-in?

Comment: @zharvey The Matrox Triplehead2go is an external USB device. Look it up http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/displayport/

Comment: @zharvey - A splitter does not perform what you're asking - it will duplicate the output on some of the displays.  You can splitter it off into infinity with enough signal repeaters, in theory.

Comment: To clarify, the th2go device stretches your desktop across 3 monitors giving you a huge workspace but it would not allow you to send each of your 4 desktops to a different monitor.